# Как работают динамические сайты?

Tags: php, html, css

Объясните, пожалуйста, как создаются, и как работают динамические сайты. Со статическими все более чем понятно: просто создаешь HTML документ, подсоединяешь к нему скрипты, стили и прочее, и все. Вот он сайт. А как сделать динамический сайт? Такой, чтобы нужную иноформацию для страниц брал из базы данных. 
P.S. Код мне мне нужен,мне нужно объяснение того, как, что и с чем взаимодейтствует, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возьмите любой учебник про php, там всё будет понятно описано.

Comment: сайт получает запрос, но не переходит на него (как файл), а обрабатывает и формирует ответ (страницу). Реально, файла-страницы нет, поэтому сайт называют динамическим

Comment: берите node.js - будет всё ищо динамичнее ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если коротко, то всё работает примерно так. Для начинающего веб-программиста рекомендуется выбрать язык php.

У вас есть [веб-сервер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80), если вы выбрали php, то это либо [Apache](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) либо [Nginx](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx). В двух словах веб-сервер принимает HTTP-запросы обрабатывает их и выдаёт HTTP-ответы, то есть действует как распределительный щеток или коммутатор, если грубо говорить. Есть [php](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/) - это [интерпретируемый](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) язык программирования, и есть база данных [mysql](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/) - это хранилище данных. Так же есть HTTP (протокол передачи гипертекста) - это набор правил по которым отправляются и принимаются запросы.

Схема работы в целом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что касается "с чего начать". Думаю самый простой способ установить к себе на компьютер веб сервер и базу данных [денвер](http://www.denwer.ru/), [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/ru/) если линукс то [lamp](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-ubuntu-14-04-ru). И пробовать писать на чистом php (без всяких фреймворком и тем более CMS) ну например свою [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), пример [MVC на php](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ba3M3_Myrqg)

Comment: У меня давно все есть, PHP немного знаю. Проблема в другом. Я не знаю, как начать создавать его (Сайт). Я понял, что динамика значит, что есть шаблонная страница, где в нужных местах есть переменные PHP. Из базы данных берутся данные, и подставляются в эту страницу вместо переменных. Шаблон создается с помощью вызовов required 'header' и 'footer', между которыми есть пустое пространство, где и стоят переменные (Упрощенно). Но... Где именно этим переменным присваиваются значения из БД? Допустим, я хочу получить страницу со статьей id=14, нажав на ссылку на главной, как это сделать?

Comment: а, для начала в теле php файла можно писать код. Но это для начала. Так сказать что бы пощупать его. Ну вот, например, http://php720.com/how-to-start

Answer (score 2):

Привет.

На теле страницы будет php код который выводит статью из базы по id.

А id берется из урл страницы, например: **domain.com/page.php?id=14**

То есть если пользователь зайдет на страницу **domain.com/page.php?id=14** то выводится статья с **id 14**, если на страницу **domain.com/page.php?id=15** то выводится статья с **id 10** итд...

Comment: То есть все так просто? Нужно ПРЯМО на шаблонной странице написать PHP код, который бы связывался с БД, и вынимал из нее нужную статью, причем данные для выборки статьи он будет брать из GET запроса? Ссылка на нужную мне статью будет такой, как вы показали?

Comment: Да все просто, если нужно только вывести статью по id. Работу с БД, обработку данных итд нужно делать перед выводом статьи, а после этого, в html коде, в нужном месте написать пхп код для вывода, например: <?php echo $article ?>

Примерно так должна выглядеть страница:

<?php

получить ид статьи

связ с БД...

Обработка...

присвоение полученных данных в переменную article

?>

<html>

<body>

<article>

<?php echo $article ?>

</aritcle>

</body>

</html>

Comment: Спасибо большое